# Schengen Visa Validity Date Mistake?

Tags: schengen, norway

I applied for a student residence permit for Norway and I was granted a visa that is valid for the wrong dates.
There are two divisions to a semester in the school in Norway. The first is August Block which starts on August 14 and ends on September 1. The second is the Autumn parallel which starts on September 5 and ends on December 22. All the subjects that I have been granted by the school are on the Autumn parallel period (Sept. 5 - Dec. 22) and the problem is that my Schengen visa only allows me to study for the August Block period (August 14 - September 1) since I have been granted a visa valid for July 24 to September 1 only. Could this perhaps be a mistake on their part in that they may have overlooked the dates that I will be studying in Norway? What can I do to fix it? Should I re-apply?

Comment: Did you actually get a schengen visa?

Comment: Yes, they granted me a visa valid for the August Block, not for the Autumn Parallel :(

Comment: What I mean is that a Schengen visa is the wrong one as it would have a max validity of 90 days anyway. It's not a country - specific residence or study visa?

Comment: It's the type D single-entry schengen visa

Comment: What dates did you ask for on the visa application?

Comment: I did not ask for any dates because there was no interview, I only needed to submit the official documents for my case. The duration of my study is however mentioned clearly in the admission letter from the university which I gave them. Now, I just called the VFS Global Help line and they told me that the visa type granted allows me to enter Norway and get my residence permit once I arrive? I remember the school in Norway told us that they have scheduled an appointment with the police, maybe that's when we get the permits? I have yet to confirm this with my outbound student coordinator here.

Answer (score 3):

Contact Norwegian embassy or consulate that has issued you the visa and explain them the situation. They may be able to fix this within days.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me recently. Italian embassy issued a visa with a validity of 30-6-19 till 13-8-19. It was five days short of my intended travel itinerary but number of days of stay was 30 which was correctly counted as per my intended travel stay within European countries. But issuing me a five day short of my intended departure from Europe it really messed up my travel plan. I immediately reached out to VFS they couldn't help they told me to contact Italian embassy so I emailed them and they gave me an appointment a day later to come to the embassy then they took my passport to give it back with a new visa with correct date in few days.

Italian embassy in Dhaka, Bangladesh helped me out! 5 star to them

Comment: This was probably better as a comment to the existing answer, but at least it *was* an attempt to answer the existing question ("Go ask the relevant embassy - it worked for me."